# How to create livegraph from an image in matplotlib

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, user-interface, matplotlib

Let me First explain what I'm trying to do

I want 8  **real time** graphs in a tkinter GUI screen. The data of these graphs basically come from some usb port device(the code for which works absolutely fine). The graphs should refresh themselves every 1 second. I used matplotlib.backends module and matplotlib.animation module for this.

But while running this code the output produces the graphs in a weird manner and that too not in real time

```
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from tkinter import *

def getvalues():
    myfile=open("sample.txt",'r').read()
    tmp_list = myfile.split('\n')
    xarr=[]
    yarr=[]
    for eachline in tmp_list:
        if len(eachline)>1:
            x,y=eachline.split(',')
            xarr.append(int(x))
            yarr.append(float(y))
    return (xarr,yarr)

def animate(i):
    x,y=getvalues()
    canvas=[]
    for i in range(4):
        fig=Figure(figsize=(3,2),dpi=100)
        plt = fig.add_subplot(4,2,i+1)
        plt.plot(x,y, color="#0000FF")
        plt.set_xlim(0, 50)
        plt.set_ylim(0, 10)
        #plt.legend(["Sensor " + repr(i + 1)])
        canvas.append(FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, animation_window))
        canvas[i].draw()
        canvas[i].get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
    for i in range(4,8):
        fig=Figure(figsize=(3,2),dpi=100)
        plt = fig.add_subplot(4,2,i-3)
        plt.plot(x,y,color="#0000FF")
        plt.set_xlim(0, 50)
        plt.set_ylim(0, 10)
        #plt.legend(["Sensor " + repr(i + 1)])
        canvas.append(FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, animation_window))
        canvas[i].draw()
        canvas[i].get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
root=Tk()
root.title("testing...")
fig=Figure(figsize=(3,2),dpi=100)
animation_window = Toplevel(root)
animation_window.title("For Stackoverflow")
animate(0)  #otherwise the plots won't show up
ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,interval=1000)
root.mainloop()
```

Basically what I need is

- A good presentation
- realtime plotting

I have tried everything in my might; Any help would be greatly appreciated...